# How to catch the return of a serial port after sending a command?

Tags: c#, .net, c, serial-port

How to catch the return of a serial port after sending a command? The return is OK. How do i read?
I tried using readLine () and ReadExisting () did not work.

```
        serialPort.PortName = "COM1";
            serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort.Open();
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                // Send command
                serialPort.Write("at");

                // string data = portaSerial.ReadLine();


                // Close serial port
                serialPort.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need attach an EventHandler to the [DataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx).

From above link:

> Represents the method that will handle the data received event of a SerialPort object

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}
```

which you will either attach in your designer or programically like this.

```
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

---

You are attaching your DataReceivedEvent handler each time you click your button, plus as Greg mentioned you are closing your port as soon as you send your data. see if something like this works. I do not have any serial devices to test this on though. I would usually just open the port at the beginning of your session and leave it open till you were done with all communications.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort.PortName = "Com1";
        serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecievedHandler);
        openSerial();

    }

    void DataRecievedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        MessageBox.Show(indata);
        closeSerial();

    }
    public void openSerial()
    {
        if (!serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Open();
    }

    public void closeSerial()
    {
        if (serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openSerial();
        serialPort.Write("Hello");

    }
}
```

Comment: I still can not. I am beginner in C#. This is my current code: http://pastebin.com/hK5MjFUz

Comment: @Mark do you have any idea if we put initial command i.e. /?!\r\n to communicate with device how device sends back the response and how we can able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading from, and writing to, the serial port from different threads.  You can either spin another thread to block on `ReadLine()` or you can wire up the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` to receive an event whenever data arrives on the serial port.

Also keep in mind that the `DataReceived` event is **not** guaranteed to be raised for every byte received.  You need to use the `BytesToRead` property to check how many bytes are in the buffer.

Comment: I still can not. I am beginner in C#. This is my current code: pastebin.com/hK5MjFUz

Comment: @Juninho - You are closing the serial port as soon as you write to it.  You need to keep it open so that you can receive data.

Comment: I'll leave it open and try again. Thank you!